# Syntax error at or near "$3" occurs while using mybatis <foreach> statement

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, mybatis

I'm having trouble with my code using foreach in mybatis, and it keeps noticing that syntax error is occurring around '$3' which I never used in query.

I tried changing the type of parameter

1. from ArrayList to List,
2. from ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<String>.

The version of mybatis is 3.0 and the database is postgres.

here is my query.

```
<XML file>
<mapper namespace="some.namespace.service.impl.SomeServiceImpl">
<select id="someId" parameterType="someCVO" resultType="someVO">
    ...
    where date_column >= date #{startDate} and
          date_column &lt; date #{endDate} + integer '1' and
        <foreach collection="menu" item="item" index="index" separator="or" open="(" close=")">
            column = #{item}
        </foreach>
</select>
```

And this is the error message:

`Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"`

Comment: `item="item index="index"` you're missing a `"` there

Comment: The `$3` is a parameter placeholder in the generated SQL statement, meaning something is going wrong with turning your mybatis statement into SQL.

Comment: I think it might be referring to the foreach part, which handles the third value. 1=startDate, 2=endDate, 3=item. "Bad SQL grammar []" might indicate thta the menu collection is empty.

Comment: sorry, missing " after item in query was a typo. i edited this thanks.

Comment: @Psymonkey You should check the actual SQL by enabling DEBUG level logging. If you need further assistance, please add the logged SQL to the question.